# C# Restarting a console application

Tags: c#

I've created a small application that does a small conversion. At the end of the program I've created a method that allows the user to make another calculation if they press 'r'. All I want it to do is if they press r, take them back to the beginning of Main, else terminate program. I do not want to use goto. This is what I've got so far, and the error I'm getting.

http://puu.sh/juBWP/c7c3f7be61.png

Comment: Please post code as text (properly formatted) - link to image on random site is not really welcome on SO and additionally it can disappear and render the post completely useless for future readers.

Comment: Noted. Won't do it again, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you use another function instead of Main(). Please refer to the code below:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        doSomething();
    }

    public static void WouldYouLikeToRestart()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press r to restart");
        ConsoleKeyInfo input = Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine();

        if (input.KeyChar == 'r')
        {
            doSomething();
        }
    }

    public static void doSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do Something");
        WouldYouLikeToRestart();
    }
```

Comment: Yes this would make it recursive, Which is terribly insane if the program has to restart from within a for loop.

Answer (score 3):

A while loop would be a good fit, but since you say the program should run **and then** give the user the option to run again, an even better loop would be a Do While.  The difference between while and Do While is that Do While will always run at least once.

```
        string inputStr;

        do
        {
            RunProgram();

            Console.WriteLine("Run again?");
            inputStr = Console.ReadLine();
        } while (inputStr == "y");

        TerminateProgram();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you want to repeat something so of course you should use a while loop. Use a while loop to wrap all your code up like this:

```
while (true) {
    //all your code in the main method.
}
```

And then you prompt the user to enter 'r' at the end of the loop:

```
if (Console.ReadLine () != "r") {//this is just an example, you can use whatever method to get the input
    break;
}
```

If the user enters r then the loop continues to do the work. `break` means to stop executing the stuff in the loop.